# Appcelerator Titanium - Problems detected with the SDK settings

Tags: android, sdk, appcelerator

So I have the error in the title, I have got several fresh copies of the Android SDK and Titanium. Still getting the error. I tried several other fixes non worked.

[image: The error I am getting.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For install Titanium SDK, i always recommend (Windows):

1. Unnistall all Android references, Node.js, Titanium SDK (Users\\AppData\Roaming\Titanium), clean all folders and registry (ccleaner or other) and reboot system.
2. Unzip Android SDK
   [r22](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/06/updating-to-android-r23-tools/)
   and install or update any Android Machines less Android SDK
   (android.bat)
3. Install [Android
   NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)
4. Set ANDROID_HOME and NDK_HOME at OS Path (+ reboot)
5. Install Latest Titanium Studio SDK + Node.js
6. Check Android SDK and NDK over Titanium SDK preferences

Comment: So the environment variables are set at 4? Do I need Android NDK?

Comment: Android NDK should be installed for compile Android modules and yes you must check or add environment variables at Control Panel - System - Advanced Options - Environment Variables also it is recommended the JAVA_HOME variable with [JDK 6 32bit](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Prerequisites) folder

Answer (score 3):

I chatted with Ricardo Alcocer from Appcelerator, because we have problems like this with every Titanium Update.

He suggested this (after some trying out):

- Remove the .titanium folder in your home directory. So that would be - on windows - /users/yourname/.titanium. It will be recreated. (You could make a backup)
- Check the titanium (not Studio) configuration in a command window by running 'titanium setup check' (see http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/03/quick-tip-use-the-titanium-cli-to-find-details-about-your-configuration/).

  - If there is a problem with the Android or SDK location, use titanium setup for reconfiguring. It has a nice menu.
  - Restart Studio, choose to configure Android, and choose the right Ti SDK for your project.

Hope this helps!

Jelmer